# Python Pillow:Load Image with data

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I need to know how to load image with its data
I use `base64` module to read the data

```py
print(base64.b64encode(open('FILENAME','rb').read()))
```

which gives me the image's data
I need something like

```py
img=Load(imgdata)  #instead of Image.open()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to base64 encode a JPEG/PNG, or any other representation of an image:

```
import base64

# Base64 encode a PNG/JPEG image
b64 = base64.b64encode(open('image.png','rb').read())
```

---

And here's how to decode and get your image back:

```
import io
from PIL import Image

# Base64 decode and convert from PNG/JPEG to PIL Image
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(b64)))
```

---

As an alternative, if you were using **OpenCV**, you might want to get back a Numpy array that **OpenCV** uses for image processing, in which case you could do:

```
import cv2

NumpyIM = cv2.imdecode(np.asarray(bytearray(base64.b64decode(b64))),0)
```

Note that this would have the blue and green channels interchanged vis-à-vis PIL/Pillow, i.e. BGR vs RGB.

---

**Keywords**: OpenCV, PIL, Pillow, Python, image processing, base64 encoded, encoding, decoding, decoded, imencode, imdecode, BytesIO, io.BytesIO.

Comment: i just use your second example(io)